# Flutter Target of URI doesn't exist

Tags: flutter, dart, uri

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kSA6G.png)

I just cloned a flutter project from GitHub, and after doing so, I get multiple errors stating (Flutter Target of URI doesn't exist)  the original developer told me that the project works fine for him, I am relatively new to flutter.

I looked online and found a person with a similar problem, they stated that dart fix --apply worked for them, but I tried it and it did nothing, I also tried 'flutter pub get' and still no fix, I am certain that the problem is caused by remixicons, but I don't know how to fix it.

Comment: Actually that path provided first check do you have any folder name packages and in that koulch_ui if it's exist give that path else get that folder first

Comment: Thank you  shaikh, I managed to fix it <3